# Get network connections from /proc/net/sockstat

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, proc

I founds this information in /proc which displays sockets:

```
$ cat /proc/net/sockstat 
sockets: used 8278
TCP: inuse 1090 orphan 2 tw 18 alloc 1380 mem 851
UDP: inuse 6574
RAW: inuse 1
FRAG: inuse 0 memory 0
```

Can you help me to find what these values means? Also are these values enough reliable or I need to search for it somewhere else?

Is these other way to find information about the TCP/UDP connections in Linux?

Comment: it'd all be in the kernel source somewhere...

Comment: @MarcB I also agree but there should be some easy way to get this information.

Comment: indeed. that could be your contribution to the OSS world... a site documenting all of this stuff.

Answer (score 4):

> Can you help me to find what these values means?

As per code [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/net/ipv4/proc.c#L50) the values are number of sockets in use (TCP / UDP), number of orphan TCP sockets (socket that applications have no more handles to, they already called `close()`). TCP `tw` I am not sure but, based on structure name (tcp_death_row), those are the sockets to be definitively destroyed in near future? `sockets` represent the number of allocated sockets (as per my understand, contemplates TCP sockets in different states) and `mem` is number of pages allocated by TCP sockets (memory usage).

[This](https://blog.tsunanet.net/2011/03/out-of-socket-memory.html) article has some discussions around this topic.

Comment: FYI I believe that the `tw`  is the TCP sockets in TIME_WAIT state, but not sure. At least the numbers match when comparing with outputs from `ss -s` or `netstat -| grep -c TIME_WAIT`..

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding the `/proc/net/sockstat` is The most reliable place to look for that information. I often use it myself, and to have one single server to manage 1MM simultaneous connections that was the only place I could reliably count that information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `netstat` command which itself utilizes the `/proc` filesystem but prints information more readable for humans.

If you want to display the current tcp connections for example, you can issue the following command:

```
netstat -t
```

Check `man netstat` for the numerous options.